# Automatic wraparound tiling painting app? Like Procreate symmetry, but without mirror reflection

Tags: sketch-app, tiles, procreate

I'm looking for a painting/graphics app (non-subscription and preferably free) (iPad or Android) that can use a pressure stylus *and* can do wraparound drawing.

Something similar to the "Mirror" symmetry that Procreate has, but *without* the mirror/reflection.

The feature is demonstrated here for those not familiar with it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBBT7xlr4Nk#t=291

I want to be able to do repeating tiled patterns so that when I draw it automatically draws in the quadrants next to mine.  Just not mirrored.  Procreate can do mirrored *or* mirrored and reflected (what they call rotation symmetry) but for some reason didn't just add the option for non-mirrored symmetry.

Any clues to an app that can do this, or what this feature would be called?

Update:  I just discovered that gimp has this feature and it's "Symmetry Painting" set to "Tiling", and you can actually run gimp on a tablet - though I haven't yet figured out how to access the full features in the app version. While I love gimp on my desktop, I was hoping for more of a "paintbrush" style less complicated sketch program similar to Procreate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this queston preferably belongs to software recomendation stackexhange.

Comment: Oh interesting - I didn't realize that SE site existed - though I confess I'm skeptical it will get knowledgeable graphics folks on it - or am I being too skeptical?

Answer (score 0):

Try Krita (krita.org) it's free and Open Source.  Works on Linux, Windows and Mac.

1. Create a new document, with a canvas size suitable for your tile,
2. Hit <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle into tiled Wrap mode.
3. Paint your design.  Note: You can enable or totally disable symmetry in the tool options along the top.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: I'm aware that Krita has this - but it does not run on an iPad or Android tablet.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar There's a Krita app (in beta) for Android. https://krita.org/en/item/first-krita-beta-for-android-and-chromeos-in-play-store/ - sorry, I've no idea how functional it is. Haven't tested it.